# Javascript Loop function starts running slow after a good start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Js script that draws 800 perfect fitted tiles on the document pretty fast..My goal is to draw them one by one very fast to create some loading effect. i like the starting speed of it but after 100 it starts slowing down and gets boring... Is there some solution or is it to much work for js ?

[Here is the code and a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rT5rL/)

```
var Gen_height=$(document).height()-21;
var Gen_width=$(document).width()-41;
var wid=Gen_width/40;
var hei=Gen_height/20;
var rot=40*20;

contrail();

var counter=0;

function contrail() {
    if (counter < rot) {
        $('body').append('<div id="box" style="width:' + wid + 'px; height:' + hei + 'px;"><div style="padding-top:15px;"><center>' + counter + '</center></div></div>');
        counter++
    }
    setTimeout(contrail, 0);
};
});
```

Comment: For starters you can stop using jQuery. Also `setTimeout(func, 0)` won't work as expected ebcause different browsers / systems will need more or less time to process it.

Comment: Ran really fast on my machine.  This is probably going to depend heavily on the specs of the machine that this code runs on.

Comment: Ooops ! :( well .. that a big downside

Comment: Why you are interested in `setTimeout(contrail,0)`? to make it asynchronous?

Comment: Suggestion: If you really want fast and constant speed in every machine, [`canvas`](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html) is for you.

Comment: why would you want to do that? everytime you append something to the body, your browser will redraw the whole body. besides that, the DOM is the slowest api someone could use with javascript. you should consider using canvas (2d or 3d. doesnt matter though 3d is faster in drawing 2d)

Comment: Yes.. only for that reason ... i had it in a for loop but i wanted some effect also so i tried this. Or if can i could find a way to have pauses in my for loop

Comment: hmmm..so i guess i must mingle with canvas a little bit.. Thanks everyone for caring !

Comment: Canvas is a good idea, but IE<9 does not support it.

Answer (score 3):

As describe in comments, it is not the best approach due to user computer perfomence. You should create your div and display them with an animation using JQueryUI for example like this : http://jsfiddle.net/rT5rL/13/

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.hide();
while(counter <= rot) 
{
   $container.append('<div id="box" style="width:' + wid + 'px; height:' + hei + 'px;"><div style="padding-top:15px;"><center>' + counter + '</center></div></div>');
   counter++;
}

 $container.slideDown(1000);
```

More effects here : http://jqueryui.com/effect/#easing

```
$container.animate( { height: "show" }, 2000, 'easeInOutBounce');
```

Comment: Your solution is a lot friendly to the user and i like it. i will keep it until i change it into canvas. Thanks for your time !